# Travis Failure: "cannot load such file -- eventmachine"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, thin, travis-ci

I'm having an issue when Travis attempts to build my application using `thin`. Executing `bundle exec rake` fails with the message:

```
cannot load such file -- eventmachine
```

I tried explicitly adding the eventmachine gem to my Gem file before adding `thin` and executing `gem install eventmachine` on the command line in my `before_script` of my `.travis.yml`. Eventually I removed `thin` completely form the required gems and it is now failing with the message:

```
cannot load such file -- pry
```

which is caused by the `activesupport` gem. I have done exhaustive googling but haven't a clue as to what might be causing these failures.

By the way, I am developing on a windows machine.

Here is my Travis log:

```
Using worker: worker-linux-7-1.bb.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-11
git.1
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/myrepo/MyRepo.git myrepo/MyRepo
Cloning into 'myrepo/MyRepo'...
remote: Counting objects: 1249, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (804/804), done.
remote: Total 1249 (delta 392), reused 1221 (delta 366)
Receiving objects: 100% (1249/1249), 8.12 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (392/392), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd myrepo/MyRepo
git.3
$ git checkout -qf fda5646974830b77d0fc1733293723694e0df7ad
$ rvm use 2.0.0 --install --binary --fuzzy
Using /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353
$ export BUNDLE_GEMFILE=$PWD/Gemfile
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
$ rvm --version
rvm 1.25.14 (version) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
$ gem --version
2.2.2
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.5.3
Applying fix for NPM certificates
before_install.1
$ export DISPLAY=:99.0
before_install.2
$ sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
Starting virtual X frame buffer: Xvfb.
install
$ bundle install --deployment
Fetching source index from http://rubygems.org/
Fetching git://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record.git
Cloning into bare repository '/home/travis/build/myrepo/MyRepo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/i18n-active_record-ed2f6232678ed3ab6dae7c41c2e30081edcdafa8'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 167, done.
remote: Total 167 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (167/167), 24.89 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (64/64), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Cloning into '/home/travis/build/myrepo/MyRepo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/i18n-active_record-55507cf59f8f'...
done.
Installing rake (10.1.1)
Installing i18n (0.6.9)
Installing minitest (4.7.5)
Installing multi_json (1.8.4)
Installing atomic (1.1.14)
Installing thread_safe (0.1.3)
Installing tzinfo (0.3.38)
Installing activesupport (4.0.0)
Installing builder (3.1.4)
Installing erubis (2.7.0)
Installing rack (1.5.2)
Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
Installing actionpack (4.0.0)
Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
Installing treetop (1.4.15)
Installing mail (2.5.4)
Installing actionmailer (4.0.0)
Installing activemodel (4.0.0)
Installing activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Installing arel (4.0.2)
Installing activerecord (4.0.0)
Installing acts_as_list (0.4.0)
Installing addressable (2.3.5)
Installing awesome_print (1.2.0)
Installing coderay (1.1.0)
Installing better_errors (1.1.0)
Installing debug_inspector (0.0.2)
Installing binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
Installing uniform_notifier (1.4.0)
Installing bullet (4.8.0)
Installing callsite (0.0.11)
Installing xpath (2.0.0)
Installing capybara (2.2.1)
Installing json (1.8.1)
Installing carrierwave (0.9.0)
Installing image_optimizer (1.2.1)
Installing carrierwave-imageoptimizer (1.2.1)
Installing childprocess (0.5.1)
Installing chronic (0.10.2)
Installing chunky_png (1.3.0)
Installing coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
Installing execjs (2.0.2)
Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
Installing thor (0.18.1)
Installing railties (4.0.0)
Installing coffee-rails (4.0.1)
Installing columnize (0.3.6)
Installing fssm (0.2.10)
Installing sass (3.2.14)
Installing compass (0.12.2)
Installing compass-rails (1.1.3)
Installing rest-client (1.6.7)
Installing docile (1.1.3)
Installing simplecov-html (0.8.0)
Installing simplecov (0.8.2)
Installing tins (1.0.0)
Installing term-ansicolor (1.3.0)
Installing coveralls (0.7.0)
Installing safe_yaml (1.0.1)
Installing crack (0.4.2)
Installing daemons (1.1.9)
Installing database_cleaner (1.2.0)
Installing debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
Installing debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.1)
Installing debugger (1.6.5)
Installing delorean (2.1.0)
Installing diff-lcs (1.2.5)
Installing launchy (2.4.2)
Installing email_spec (1.5.0)
Installing factory_girl (4.4.0)
Installing factory_girl_rails (4.4.0)
Installing multipart-post (2.0.0)
Installing faraday (0.9.0)
Installing forgery (0.5.0)
Installing foundation-rails (5.1.1.0)
Installing geocoder (1.1.9)
Installing tilt (1.4.1)
Installing haml (4.0.5)
Installing haml-rails (0.5.1)
Installing haml_assets (0.2.2)
Installing hike (1.2.3)
Installing sprockets (2.10.1)
Installing handlebars_assets (0.15)
Installing httpauth (0.2.1)
Using i18n-active_record (0.0.2) from git://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record.git (at master)
Installing i18n-js (2.1.2)
Installing jquery-rails (3.1.0)
Installing turbolinks (2.2.1)
Installing jquery-turbolinks (2.0.2)
Installing jquery-ui-rails (4.2.0)
Installing jwt (0.1.11)
Installing rack-contrib (1.1.0)
Installing meta_request (0.2.8)
Installing subexec (0.2.3)
Installing mini_magick (3.7.0)
Installing nested_form (0.3.2)
Installing oauth (0.4.7)
Installing oauth2 (0.8.1)
Installing paper_trail (3.0.0)
Installing pry-rails (0.3.2)
Using bundler (1.5.3)
Installing sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
Installing rails (4.0.0)
Installing rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
Installing rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
Installing rails_12factor (0.0.2)
Installing redis (3.0.7)
Installing rspec-core (2.14.7)
Installing rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
Installing rspec-mocks (2.14.5)
Installing rspec (2.14.1)
Installing rspec-rails (2.14.1)
Installing ruby-drupal-hash (0.0.3)
Installing rubyzip (1.1.0)
Installing sass-rails (4.0.1)
Installing websocket (1.0.7)
Installing selenium-webdriver (2.39.0)
Installing sorcery (0.8.5)
Installing thin (1.6.1)
Installing uglifier (2.4.0)
Installing webmock (1.17.3)
Cannot write a changed lockfile while frozen.
Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
Post-install message from haml:
HEADS UP! Haml 4.0 has many improvements, but also has changes that may break
your application:
* Support for Ruby 1.8.6 dropped
* Support for Rails 2 dropped
* Sass filter now always outputs <style> tags
* Data attributes are now hyphenated, not underscored
* html2haml utility moved to the html2haml gem
* Textile and Maruku filters moved to the haml-contrib gem
For more info see:
http://rubydoc.info/github/haml/haml/file/CHANGELOG.md
before_script
$ psql -c 'create database myrepo_test;' -U postgres
CREATE DATABASE
$ bundle exec rake
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- eventmachine
/home/travis/build/myrepo/MyRepo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin.rb:7:in `require'
/home/travis/build/myrepo/MyRepo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
/home/travis/build/myrepo/MyRepo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/travis/build/myrepo/MyRepo/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/travis/build/myrepo/MyRepo/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The command "bundle exec rake" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```